# What part of speech is "So" in this sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech, interjections

This is the sentence,

> So you have come? I have been anxiously waiting for you

So, I have read online that the word "So" can have multiple functions and can be of different part of speech depending upon the context. Could be an adverb, interjection, adjective etc

So, what part "So" is playing in the sentence given above? It is said that "So" can function as an interjection if used to describe a surprise... I think it is playing the role of interjection here but this sentence doesn't look too much like a surprise. Please provide your opinion and tell the function "So" is playing here. Thank you!

Comment: Used in this way, it is a conjunction.  "So" can be used to introduce a question.

Comment: I think in many if not *all* contexts where ***So*** is used to introduce an utterance, it has the generic meaning ***Given the [aforementioned] circumstances / information...*** Note that ***So** [statement]* is usually equivalent to *[Statement] **then***, where alternatives such as ***therefore*** and ***in that case*** can appear either before or after *[Statement]*.

Comment: But "aforementioned" obviously wouldn't be appropriate in your example if it was *the first utterance* (in a *conversation*). As the first word in the initial conversational utterance, ***So*** is a much looser / vaguer term, often meaning almost nothing at all (though my guess is non-native speakers tend to overuse it as a meaningless conversational introduction more often than the natives). On the other hand, it can reasonably be used in contexts such as yours with something of the sense ***Unexpectedly*** - where *[Statement]* is something the speaker thinks is "unusual / remarkable".

Comment: You might like to ask yourself exactly why you started your third line in this question with ***So,** I have read...* What do *you* think that initial word adds to the meaning? (I suspect *nothing*, obviously! :)

Comment: Often, initial ***So*** is no more than a "discourse marker", equivalent to clearing one's throat to catch the attention of your intended audience, or to prefacing the subsequent statement with ***Apropos nothing...***

Comment: It can only be an adverb, here functioning as an adjunct.